# Customising and Deleting a Cell in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image][image]

I am converting a sample html app to ios  i have a table view with edit button as shown in figure.when i click that edit button the buttons with (-) symbols should appear for all the cells and if i click that minus button that particular cell should get delete.I tried it but i can add only two the last row.Here I am loading the cell from the nib.

Answer (score 1):

If you post your current code we can help you better, however I suggest you to implement this algorithm:

1. Reload your table, set a default style to your custom cell to hide the "-" button
2. If user touch the "edit" button, reload you table and set a delete style to your custom cell to show the "-" button
3. When user clicks the "-" button, delete it from datasource and reload your table

Comment: - (IBAction)editbtn:(id)sender {
    


    if(!cell.isSelected)
    {
                    cell.minusbuttn.hidden=NO;
        
    }
}

Comment: It is not the algorithm I suggested :)

Comment: suggest me the code that i have to write when that button is clicked

Comment: Stackoverflwo doesn't work like this: you have to write the code and demonstrate your tries, then we can modified your code to let it work. You are asking for the fish, not for the knowledge of fishing.